# How can I stop dye from rubbing off burlap?

Tags: fabric, dye

I recently acquired some burgundy burlap to use in re-upholstering some straight backed chairs. Problem is,  the color comes off if you rub hard against it (like sitting down!). Any suggestions on how I can set the dye job on this material? Returning it isn't an option.

Thanks,
Jackie

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that might work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to guess what went wrong in the dying process, but I am assuming you have a natural jute fiber burlap. You will probably have to dye the fabric again. What usually works is [Rit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001763GIO) - which you can get at pretty much a y fabric store. Be careful, it is a little caustic and will stain your skin.

If you want to try to fix the dye, don’t use salt or vinegar - caustic soda *might* work, but you probably want to get [retayne](http://www.pburch.net/dyeing/FAQ/settingdye.shtml) as it is described here. Apparently also available at quilting and fabric stores, I must say that I do not know the product but the science seems sound.

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially the lead to the Retayne page. Lots of good information there.

Comment: @JackieBell if it answered your question, please feel free to mark this response as correct.